# Sum all rows that have the same id in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, aggregate-functions

I'm using sqlite3, I have the following table:

[image: Table]

"who" stands for the id of users. say who with id "4" stands for "John". John made 7 purchases. I would like to have a select query that sums all the shares of John. so the select query on shares based on who of "4" returns 113. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `where` clause and a `sum()`:

```
select sum(shares) as total_shares
from mytable
where who = 4
```

Or if you want the result for all users at once, with each user on a separate row:

```
select who, sum(shares) as total_shares
from mytable
group by who
```

You can also count how many records each user has if you like:

```
select who, sum(shares) as total_shares, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by who
```